# tcl string command does not work with regexp backreference

Tags: string, tcl, regsub

see code below, as an example, I am trying to find use regsub with backrefeence as means of selectively using `string toupper`. I am not getting what I have expected.
See simple example below (yes, I know that I can use `string toupper $string 0 0`, however, this is just for showing the principle, in a simple example).

```
> puts [ regsub {^(.)} "min" "s\\1" ]
smin
> puts [ regsub {^(.)} "min" [ string toupper "\\1" ] ]
min
```

As can be seen, string toupper applied on backreference does not work, but the backrefernce can be used in a double quote operation.
I am using TCL ver. 8.6

Comment: ... and there's no way it could work, as the `string toupper` command gets executed BEFORE the `regsub` command.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/EjXgje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string toupper` is working, but not doing what you want; `string toupper "\\1"` is just the string `\1` so the `regsub` isn't having much effect. The problem is that `regsub` doesn't have any way of doing “run this command at the substitution sites”; I've been wanting to fix that for years, but have never actually done so (too many projects for this one to make it to the fore).

Instead, you need to `regsub` in a command substitution into the string and then `subst` the result, but in order to do that, you need to first make the string otherwise safe to `subst` with `string map`. Fortunately, that's actually pretty simple.

I've split this apart to make it easier for you to examine exactly what each stage is doing:

```
set str "here is an example with \$dollars, \[brackets\] and \\backslashes"

# Quote all of Tcl's metacharacters; there's not that many
set safer [string map {[ \\[ ] \\] \\ \\\\ $ \\$} $str]

# Inject the command we want to run where we want to run it
set withsubst [regsub {^(.)} $safer {[string toupper {\1}]}]

# Perform the substitution
set result [subst $withsubst]
```

Comment: Well, this is definitely more complex than what you would find in regexp substitution offered by, say, Ruby. I will try to cookup some wrap around procedure. Thanks

Comment: I know; it's been irritating me for years that we need to do this sort of stuff.